# Schema-tool create - class not found errors

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, composer-php

I'm trying to learn doctrine by following this [tutorial](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#generating-the-database-schema). It's the official "getting started" from doctrine website.

When it comes to generate the db-schema the tutorial suggests to use the command-line tool that ships with doctrine. The command is the following:

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

i get the following output:

```
SRC_DIR="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname "$0"`"
cd "../doctrine/orm/bin"
BIN_TARGET="`pwd`/doctrine"
cd "$SRC_DIR"
"$BIN_TARGET" "$@"
```

and nothing happens. Please note that i used composer to install doctrine, my `composer.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
    }
}
```

then i tried the following command (note the different path):

```
php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

it gives me a class not found error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\vendor\doctrine\annotations\tests\Doctrine\Tests\Common\Annotations\AbstractReaderTest.php on line 13
```

SO... i added the phpunit dependency to my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
    }
}
```

and re-run the command:

```
php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

and now i'm getting a different class not found error that i'm not able to fix:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Tests\Common\Annotations\Fixtures\AnnotationTargetAll' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\vendor\doctrine\annotations\tests\Doctrine\Tests\Common\Annotations\DocParserTest.php on line 1312
```

i'm pretty sure composer should handle all this mess auto-magically but it's not happening.

My ultimate goal is to be able to follow the tutorial mentioned at the beginning of my question in order to start learning doctrine ORM.

Can anyone help me to get the `schema-tool create` command work?

Many thanks for any help and for reading this long post!

**UPDATE**

I wanted to point out that i tried to run those commands with both the windows cmd (console) and with git bash - same result. Anyway, please confirm that i should use git bash to issue those commands, thanks

Comment: The output of the first command definitly is targeted at a linux shell. I don't know if the Git bash is sufficient, but I would expect the tutorial to clarify that it either can explicitly be used with Windows or not.

Comment: @Sven It's not specified - is it possible to run linux scripts on windows?

Comment: Maybe i should try cygwin?

Comment: No, you can't run Linux scripts on Windows, because the commands are not the same, only "similar" (like `tracerout` vs. `tracert`). Cygwin sounds like a good bet.